# how to add Grails Plugin to IntellIJ?

Tags: grails, ubuntu, plugins, intellij-idea, groove

I´m new to Grails world and Iḿ trying to import a grails application into an IntellIJ IDE but I have some issues. 
I was trying to find tutorials on how I could import and everybody says that I need to import the project as a Grails Project !

the problem is that I cant find Grails Project !!! 
there are no Grails Plugins in the IntellIJ

how could I install the Grails POlugin or enable the Grails inside the IntellIJ ?

I was searching for this issues so long with success !

my grails version is 2.1.0 and my IntellIJ is 12.0.4

edited :

I also have another issue with IntellIJ ... it keeps 
groove SDK is not configured !

Comment: Grails is [Ultimate edition feature](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html). Do you run the Ultimate version?

Comment: Actually no ! Im using the community version and I have no idea about that !

Comment: @CrazyCoder if you are sure about that ! put it in the answers so I can mark it as true !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get Grails project type you need to use IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate, the difference between the editions can be found in [this document](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html).